# Case Converted Nolle Prosequi

Tags: criminal-law, criminal-procedure, criminal-record

Jurisdiction:  Albuquerque, NM - US

Is it normal for a criminal case not pursued, originating October 2014, to have a disposition “Converted Nolle Prosequi” on August 2016, almost 23 months after the arrest date? What is the purpose/reason a disposition would be converted for a case that never even went before a grand jury (as far as I know) and to do so nearly 2 years after the initial complaint was first filed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Prosecutors have discretion

The decision to abandon a prosecution is one for the DA and for the DA’s own reasons.

Comment: I know the DA has prosecutorial discretions but that wasnt what I wanted to know. My understanding is when a case is Nolled the prosecution has decided not to pursue the case but has the discretion to pursue it at a later date though the defendants right to a speed trial would likely prevent prosecution after 6 months. 23 months is way past that, so why nolle the case, Is that the only way to close a case not pursued? In which case, the delayed deposition is likely due to DA behind on their filing not something nefarious. I wanted to know if my experience was common or if I should be concerned